# Ultra High Temperature of Samsung SM951 After Rebooting From Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, temperature, nvme

I have met a weird problem with Ubuntu and my SM951 NVMe SSD.

My laptop is ThinkPad T460s with a 256G SM951 SSD installed, and I installed dual system(Windows 10 64bit Education and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) on it. When I want to switch between them, I have to reboot or just shutdown and turn on the laptop later.

The problem is: when I reboot under Ubuntu, the SSD's temperature will go to 82C after rebooting which triggers the SSD's protection and decrease its speed to about 80MB/s, no matter I choose to use Win or Ubuntu after rebooting. But if I shutdown from Ubuntu and press the power button to start my laptop again, the problem will not happen.

Under Windows the problem will not happen, no matter I reboot or just shutdown and power on again.

I doubt that my SSD doesn't go that hot in reality for its temperature keeps reasonable (about 40~50C) during 6 hours of heavy load.

Comment: Here (http://www.overclock.net/t/1551060/official-samsung-sm951-owners-club) is a interesting thread about your SSD model, search for temperature and you'll see a problem that existed even on windows, some people solved it setting to AHCI in BIOS, while others don't.  It seem to be realated some way to _NVMe_. Also _always try to use `UEFI` instead of `Legacy`_.

Comment: Have you checked for a BIOS firmware update for your Thinkpad?

Comment: @dgonzalez  Thanks! I have checked that I am using UEFI and my laptop supports AHCI mode only. Maybe there are some other reasons...

Comment: @heynnema I have checked my BIOS version and it was true that there was a new version. But after successfully upgrading my BIOS, the problem still exists... Thanks a lot anyway!